# Order results in which it was read in. Using in()

Tags: mysql, sorting

This is my query in mysql:

```
SELECT school_id, first_name, last_name, email, blog_username, comment_username
FROM   table 
WHERE  user_id IN (100, 3,72) ;
```

The results show the two user_id's in ascending order. How can I make it so that it is ordered by in which is was received?

So instead of `3, 72, 100`  I want the results to be `100, 3, 72`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select school_id, first_name, last_name, email, blog_username, comment_username 
From table 
Where user_id IN ( 100, 3, 72 )
Order By Case 
            When user_id = 100 Then 1
            When user_id = 3 Then 2
            When user_id = 72 Then 3
            End Asc
```

Addition explanation:

What is being sought is the ability to order the rows in a custom manner. Said another way, we need to add custom cardinality to a set of values that do not conform to a standard cardinality. A Case expression can be used to do just that. Another way to accomplish the same thing would be:

```
Select school_id, first_name, last_name, email, blog_username, comment_username 
From table 
    Join (
         Select 100 As user_id, 1 As Sort
         Union All Select 3, 2
         Union All Select 72, 3
         ) As Seq
      On Seq.user_id = table.user_id
Order By Seq.Sort
```

Comment: Can you expand on how & why this solution works to resolve the question?

Comment: @Denomales - Done. In essence, I'm using the Case expression to calculate a new cardinality for the values. The Case expression acts as a transformation that converts a list of values into their cardinality value.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a function `FIELD()` which is suited for this:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(user_id, 100, 3, 72 )
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field

and in general (method is designed for `strings` but it will work just fine with numbers)

```
ORDER BY FIELD(field_name, value_1, value_2, ... )
```

However

- It makes your SQL less portable
- Ordering like this is much less efficient

Whole code

```
SELECT school_id, first_name, last_name, email, blog_username, comment_username
  FROM   table 
    WHERE  user_id IN (100, 3, 72) 
    ORDER BY FIELD(user_id, 100, 3, 72)
```

Although I would consider changing the rest of you code so you do not have to use this method.